# How to manage Laravel controllers and views in separate Git repos

Tags: git, laravel, version-control

It seems to me that a large portion of projects have repeated components. For example most projects will have a `User` model, along with a `UsersController` and user views.

Is there any way to structure a project so that each of these is pulled from a Git repo?

I want to have separate repos for each (say a repo for Users, a repo for Forum, etc) so in each new Laravel project (lets all it ProjectA, which itself would also live in a repo) I can just `git clone my_users_repo` and have the latest users code. I would also need to commit this in the ProjectA repo.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you get the answer which help you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you familiar with package? maybe  is that  what you need. See  [here](https://devdojo.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-create-a-laravel-package)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s possible.

You can use `git subtree add --prefix=user <URL for user repo> master` to add contents of  `master` branch in user repo to your project (also use for other separate repos, such as Forum).

When the user repo is updated, you can update the subtree in your project by

```
git subtree pull --prefix=user <URL for user repo> master
```

When you want to push changes to remote user remote, you can use

```
git subtree push --prefix=user <URL for user repo> master
```

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted Zoran's answer as it appears to be the more Laravel way to do this. I'd need files in different folders (views, controllers, etc.), and Laravel packages supports this.